# How to save the data in database via controller in larval

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

I Don't know where the mistake is the data is not saving into the database.Can any one help it will be use full for me. I am stuck on these for days. Thank you in advance.

My Routes

```
 Route::get('/reject','RejectionReasonsController@index');
 Route::post('/reject','RejectionReasonsController@store');
```

My Controller(RejectionReasonsController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RejectionReasonsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $record = RejectionReason::all();

        return view('reject');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){


        $record= new RejectionReason();

        $record->reason_title = request('reason_title');

        $record->save();

        return redirect('/routes');

    }
}
```

My Model file(RejectionReasons)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RejectionReasons extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['reason_title'];
}
```

My blade file(reject.blade.php)

```
                <div class="form-check">
                    <form action="/store" class="textbox" method="POST">
                        <h5><b> Select Reasons: </b></h5>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rejectReason1" name='reason_title[]' value='No responce'> No responce <br>
                        <label for="Rejection">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rejectReason2" name='reason_title[]' value='Skills mismatch'> Skills mismatch
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <div id="txtReasonRejected1" style="display: none">
                            <input type="text" id="Reasons1" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rejectReason3" name='reason_title[]' value='Culture mismatch'> Culture mismatch <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rejectReason4" name='reason_title[]' value='Salary  expectation mismatch'> Salary  expectation mismatch <br>
                        <label for="Rejection">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rejectReason5" name='reason_title[]' value='Not enough knowledge/inclination for ColoredCow'> Not enough knowledge/inclination for ColoredCow
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <div id="txtReasonRejected2" style="display: none">
                            <input type="text" id="Reasons2" />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit">Reject</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

I Don't know where the mistake is the data is not saving into the database.Can any one help it will be use full for me. I am stuck on these for days. Thank you in advance.

Comment: first dump your request data inside controller like dd($request);

Comment: As you have set the value of the name attribute of the checkbox as array reason_title[] so the value of $request->reason_title will be an array of strings. You need to implode this with ',' if you want to store it as one record or you can store multiple records by looping $request->reason_title

Comment: Unless you have another route set up `action="/store"` will not hit that controller method. Also missing a `@csrf` in your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make change in your route like this

```
Route::post('/reject','RejectionReasonsController@store')->name('reject.post');
```

then in your blade

```
<form action="{{route('reject.post')}}" class="textbox" method="POST">
    @csrf
```

Comment: The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. This is one i am getting

Comment: refresh the page,by hitting url or open in private window

Comment: add @csrf below form tag

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }} this is fine ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){


    $record= new RejectionReason();
    
    $record->reason_title = $request->reason_title;

    $record->save();

    return redirect('/routes');

}
```

You can try

If you have more  row than, you can run a loop

Comment: After clicking the reject it is not working. I think there is some mistake in form

Comment: You can take an array. so you can save data in a database multiple or a comma separator.
Like implode($request->reason_title)

Comment: you can dd($request->reasion_title) in your controller . Then you can understand .

Comment: <form action="{{ url('store')}}" class="textbox" method="POST">
@csrf
</form>
your form not correct try it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have set the value of the `name` attribute of the checkbox as array `reason_title[]`, the value of `$request->reason_title` will be an array of strings

You can store it as comma-separated-values (using `implode` helper function) if you want it to be in one record

```
public function store(Request $request){


    $record= new RejectionReason();

    $record->reason_title = implode(",", $request->reason_title);

    $record->save();

    return redirect('/routes');

}
```

If you want to store every reason title as new records you just need to loop it

```
public function store(Request $request){


    foreach($request->reason_title as $value){
        
        $record= new RejectionReason();

        $record->reason_title = $value;

        $record->save();
    }

    return redirect('/routes');
}
```

Comment: Should i remove the reason_title array from blade file and run?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If you want multi-choice then you need to keep it as an array otherwise it will be a single choice. One reason title at a time. Just print the request using dd($request) in your controller, It would help you to understand the request and data flow.

Comment: It throws my model is not declare how to i solve that

Comment: Import model before class declaration `use App\Models\RejectionReasons;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely certain that there are gonna be only a specific number of 'reasons' in your form, then better make one column for each reason in your database. i.e.

```
    class RejectionReasons extends Model
    {
     protected $fillable = ['reason_one','reason_two','reason_three' .......];
    }
```

Also in your RejectionController, you should import your Model after namespaces as

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   
   user RejectionReason;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class RejectionReasonsController extends Controller
    { ....... }
```

and yes, your form is also missing the  @csrf .